# Changing background color for non-header cells in column of p:dataTable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I would like to know how to set up background color for a specific column in a datatable.I have tried the below css code

```
.mystyle.ui-datatable .ui-datatable-data td, .mystyle.ui-datatable .ui-datatable-data td{
background-color:#B5D3A5;   
}
```

But the above seems to change the background color for all the columns in the datatable. Please let me know how to change the background color for a specific column in the datatable. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `style` and `styleClass` attributes of `p:column` for this:

```
<p:column style="background-color: red" ...>
```

This will colorize table cells *and* header cells.

If you don't want to change header cells you could do the following:

Give the column a styleClass attribute:

```
<p:column styleClass="foo" ...>
```

And then add the following style definition to your css/html:

```css
td.foo {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for the response. I tried the above already, but the thing is, It changes the background color for the header of the column as well. I dont want the style of the header to be changed. Just the background color for the column values needs to be changed.Please let me know what needs to be done to change the background color for the column values alone.

Comment: Ok, that was not clear from your question. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use headerClass attribute of p:dataTable for header style and use inline style for your requierd column as style="text-align:center;background-color:red"